# C#: Copy Section of 2D-Array

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5

i'm working on a Client-Server Game with a tilebased map.
If the user changes the visible section of the map (i.e. scrolls in any direction) i query the server for info about the new section giving X, Y, Width and Height.

The Map info is stored as 2D array

```
MapTile[,]
```

(MapTile is a simple Struct)

When the client requests a new section i want to read the section from the map tile array, for that i defined a method

```
public MapTile[,] GetMapSection(Rectangle area)
{
  [... snip validation ...]
  MapTile[,] result = new MapTile[area.Width, area.Height];

  for (Int32 y = 0; y < area.Height; ++y)
  {
    for (Int32 x = 0; x < area.Width; ++x)
    {
       result[x, y] = this.map[x + area.X, y + area.Y];
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Is there an easier (=> easier to read, understand and maintain, not necessarily faster) way to get the section from the Array?

Comment: Why don't you let the game load the whole map when one starts the game? I don't see the affort by just querying a small rect several times. You have plenty of memory out there. ;-)
For your question: You could organize your array into a 1D array and then just arraycopy the part you need. 1Darray[X+Y*Dimension]=2DArray[X][Y].

Comment: The map can be several thousand tiles big in each direction. We estimate a size of 10000x7500 tiles.

Comment: Turning the 2D array into a 1D array would of course be possible but not very maintainable with either lots of calls like this.map[GetIndex(map, x, y)] or this.map[x + (y * dimension)]. Not very nice to read.

Comment: @dbmerlin Ok, i get it. But anyhow I would divide this large area in certain small ones (eg each 1000x750 or so) if you don't do now.

Comment: @dbmerlin Hmm, I have to admit I forgot, but some time ago there were some advantages using a 1D array instead of 2d. Many games did that, but I'm out of that "business" for some years. If you hide this in a getTile(XPos,YPos) you have only one "not nice to read" place in your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not really. This seemes like a sensible and simple way to do it. The reason .NET doesn't provide any built-in method is that, unlike with a 1D array, there are a whole variety of different ways of copying/combining multidimensional arrays.

You're not really going to get faster, and I think it's perfectly maintainable. Seems like pretty fixed code anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I found a link on a MS example for arraycopy with c#

[Array copy using pointers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/28k1s2k6%28VS.80%29.aspx)